# Slow performance of embedding Mathematica Demonstrations in webpages

Tags: demonstrations

When I embed a Mathematica Demonstration in my webpage, the performance is very slow and laggy.

For instance, if I follow the instruction video and embed the [Radial Engine Demonstration](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RadialEngine/) in an HTML page (by clicking on the `</>` button and pasting the iframe code into an HTML file) takes about 5 seconds to load (that's ok) but when I drag a slider, it takes about 2 seconds for the image to update (that's a big problem). This is the case even for simpler demonstrations, such as this [magnetic field](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ACRotatingMagneticFieldPrinciple/#embed) demonstration.

Is there any way to improve performance?

Comment: `When I embed a Mathematica Demonstration in my webpage` how did you manage to run a manipulate in webpage these days? which browser are you using? Because none of the current browsers I know about support the WRI NPAPI plugin-in any more. (unless you have an old browser that is not updated?) This has been the case for may be 2 or more years now?

Comment: @Nasser As you can see if you follow OP's link, demonstrations are now embeddable thanks to Wolfram Cloud.

Comment: I have edited my question to explicitly say how I am embedding the demonstration -via the `</>` button.

Comment: @Nasser Bruce Bartlett does not seem to be embedding a `Manipulate[]` output from a Mathematica notebook, but a demonstration from Wolfram Demonstrations Project website, I suppose the demos may have been specially prepared with supporting cloud resources etc. to run in a webpage. This seems more an HTML question than one about *Mathematica* per se. Perhaps community.wolfram.com is a better forum for this question.

Comment: I couldn't find a page of yours to test, so I published some silly demo of mine at https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/c1410bf7-d2c4-4f05-8541-21e52cb21704.  Somewhere in the world there is an instance of Mathematica running on a server. Your browser has to communicate with it and decode and display the results.  I expect yours does not run any better than my wolframcloud demo. The slowness of interacting with the cloud Mathematica has been noticed by others in chat, so I suspect there's no easy fix.